# how to close rtsp-relay stream which is generated by proxy in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rtsp

I created an rtsp url to stream and play on the frontend(reactJS) and I want to close these streams when I request from frontend by camera id

```js
  app.ws("/api/stream/" + cameraId, (ws, req) => {
    connections[cameraId] = ws;

      rtspStream = proxy({
        url: rtspURL,
        verbose: true,
      });
    }
    process.setMaxListeners(0);

 });
```

how can I stop/close these streams to stop the camera playing on frontend?

I tried `ws.close();` or `ws.terminate();`  function to close stream by camera

after close stream camera streaming working or displaying on frontend

Answer (score 0):

On the client:

```js
const load = await loadPlayer({
    url: rtspURL,
    canvas
});
setTimeout(() => load.destroy(), 5000);
```